# Datastax 5.0.x on Oracle Linux 7 support

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Has anyone configured DSE 5.0.x on Oracle Linux7 (based on RHEL 7.2 or 7.3)?

I am able to install DSE 5.0.4 using tar ball method, but I am getting some "prickling" error while importing data.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but it isn't a tested platform so there could well be wrinkles.  What is the errors you see?

Comment: I am seeing issues with Python packages (missing pre-req packages)..not a major issue, but with RHEL, I could get/build a "working image" w/o much hassle.